# aggregate unique values of repeated field

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have a repeated field in my table. I want to run an aggregate query and receive the array of unique values that match my query. I've tried several various variations of this query:

```
with t as (select * from unnest([
    STRUCT("foo" as name, ["red", "blue"] as color)
  , STRUCT("foo", ["blue"])
  , STRUCT("foo", NULL)
  , STRUCT("foo", ["green"])
  , STRUCT("bar", ["orange", "black"])
  , STRUCT("bar", ["black", "white"])
]))
select
    (select color from unnest(array_concat_agg(color))) as color
from t
group by name
```

The desired results being:

```
name  | color
=====================================
foo   | ["red", "blue", "green"]
bar   | ["orange", "black", "white"]
```

This particular query gives `Aggregate function ARRAY_CONCAT_AGG not allowed in UNNEST at [10:31]`, but I don't find this error in the documentation, and I can't find an intuitive reason why such a limitation would be in place, nor how I might fix this error.

Does what I'm doing somehow inherently require an additional level of nested query?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT name, ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT color) color
FROM `project.dataset.your_table`, UNNEST(color) color
GROUP BY name
```

you can test, play with above using dummy data from your questions as

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.your_table` AS (
  SELECT * FROM UNNEST([
    STRUCT("foo" AS name, ["red", "blue"] AS color)
  , STRUCT("foo", ["blue"])
  , STRUCT("foo", NULL)
  , STRUCT("foo", ["green"])
  , STRUCT("bar", ["orange", "black"])
  , STRUCT("bar", ["black", "white"])
]))
SELECT name, ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT color) color
FROM `project.dataset.your_table`, UNNEST(color) color
GROUP BY name
```

with result as

```
Row name    color    
1   bar     orange   
            white    
            black    
2   foo     red  
            blue     
            green
```

Answer (score 0):

This gets the results that you want:

```
select t.name, array_agg(distinct color)
from (select name, array_concat_agg( color) as colors
      from t
      group by name
     ) t cross join
     unnest(colors) color
group by t.name;
```

Your query has several problems, notably the subquery with `unnest()` will return more than one row.